# Rglpk_solve_lp and glpsol(internally used by pulp glpk solver) return different values for same LP

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, glpk, pulp

The lp problem can be found at [Portfolio Optimization Problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx46maakadEJcHIzYURQbGdxWUk/edit?usp=sharing). The problem is based on cvar optimization in guy yollins presentation [R Tools for Portfolio Optimization](http://www.r-programming.org/files/RFinance2009.pdf).

When I read the lp file in R and execute it, optimal solution is found. Whereas when I do the same via glpsol, it says "LP HAS NO PRIMAL FEASIBLE SOLUTION". I'm using glpsol as [pulp](http://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/) internally uses glpsol for solving lp when solver argument is given as pulp.GLPK().

Steps to run the lp  in R:

```
library("Rglpk")
problem <- Rglpk_read_file("path/to/problem.lp", "CPLEX_LP")
solution <- Rglpk_solve_LP(problem$objective, problem$constraints[[1]], problem$constraints[[2]], problem$constraints[[3]], problem$bounds, problem$types, problem$maximum, control=list("verbose" = TRUE))
print(solution$status)
print(solution$solution)
```

Steps to run the lp in glpsol:

```
glpsol --cpxlp "path/to/problem.lp" -o output.sol
```

Any idea why? I tried seeing the code for Rglpk_solve_lp function in R. It seems to be calling the glpk c library's glp_simplex function. I'm guessing glpsol also calls glp_simplex internally.

Environment details:
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
R version: 3.02
Rglpk version: 0.5-1(GLPK version 4.52 is shipped with the source package)
glpsol version: 4.52

Comment: I'll leave it only as a comment as I am not 100% sure exactly how to diagnose a numerically unstable problem, but that would be my guess. Adding --dual to your glpsol call solved it for me.

Comment: The results seem to vary mainly due to the options passed. I'll try out different options and try to see if any specific option matches the R results and add it as answer. You saved my ass dude. Thanks

Comment: @flodel: After I looked at the source code of Rglpk and glpsol, I found that Rglpk simply calls glp_simplex(problem, NULL). Whereas glpsol passes in valid non null value for the second argument. When I made the value of 2nd argument NULL in glpsol, rebuilt the code and reran the same problem with glpsol, it returned the same output as Rglpk_solve_lp. I'll try to find out if I can replicate the same without having to modify the source code of glpsol and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding options --nopresol, --noscale, --std to glpsol command gave me the same results as Rglpk_solve_lp.

```
glpsol --cpxlp ~/Downloads/PortfolioOptimization_minReturns_0.190000.lp -o output.sol --nopresol --noscale --std
```

I had to look into glpsol's code and compare it with Rglpk package's code to figure this out.